# whats the best control for displaying text on my app

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

If I have a simple WPF app. This app runs some scripts to process data and I want to display some of that data (statistics) on the screen. What is the best control to use (text box, richtextbox, etc)?
I want the control to show data/update data as the script is running in the background.

Comment: If you only want to display text then use lightweight `TextBlock` control.

Comment: Do you want the most recent items at the top?

Answer (score 1):

Start by doing a little sketch on a paper how your form will look like. This helps you answer your own question.

Displaying statistic depends on the way you want to display them:

You can use a [DataGrid](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html) when you have to display table form statistic results.

You can use `TextBlock` when you have to display final results (kind of Aggregations, Sums, Averages etc)

The most common whay to display statistics is by using [Chart control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196502/WPF-Toolkit-Charting-Controls-Line-Bar-Area-Pie-Co)

At any time, you can refer to the [Microsoft's UX Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511258.aspx)